# Wordpress plugins priority

Tags: php, wordpress

I have two plugin in wordpress , first plugin names start with 'a' like 'aplugin' and second one names start with 'b' like 'bplugin'. Now I have a function in 'bplugin' , then want to call it from 'aplugin', Because of wordpress plugin loads priority with name ,I can't call it from 'aplugin'.Is there any way to call that without add_action method. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Actually there's a plugin for that [link]https://wordpress.org/plugins/plugins-load-order/ but you will need to use an action or hook to define plugin load orders.

Comment: [link]https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/63141/in-what-order-does-wordpress-load-plugin-files

Comment: If those are your own plugins, you can set them up using the `plugins_loaded` hook like so: `add_action( "plugins_loaded", "my_plugin_init_function", 1 )`. The advantage of this is that you can control the order in which your plugins are initialized by using the priority parameter of `add_action()` ( 1 in this example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an only way that is using with include files at first with priorities.